# Is it possible to facebook connect using Capybara Webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

Is it possible to facebook connect using Capybara-webkit driver?

All the examples I see on the Web are using the "within_window" method (like this one: https://gist.github.com/1187574) which is currently not supported by Capybara-webkit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I also found only "within_window" examples, but after some more research I found a quite recent [pull request](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/pull/314) on the [capybara-webkit repo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) that solves that [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/129) and adds support for `within_window` to the capybara-webkit gem

Probably the best way to go is to fetch the gem from Github instead of rubygems.

```
gem "capybara-webkit", git: "https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit.git"
```

Let me know if it works. I haven't really tested out.

Comment: this pull request has not been merged into master so you'll have to git clone the fork instead.

Comment: FYI that request has since been merged into master so this should now be built standard w/ Capybara-webkit